# How to get all users from LDAP AD group using ActiveDirectory library?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I have this function 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2#getUsersForGroup
But it returns nothing when I invoke it with the CN of a group that exists.
The group exists and it has users, but the function is not returning any.

```
ad.authenticate(config.USERNAME, config.PASSWORD, function(err, auth) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if (auth) {
    console.log('Authenticated!');


    let groupName = 'ORG-Application-ContactCentre-ORG-RSV-BusAdmin';
    ad.findGroup(groupName, function(err, group) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (! group) console.log('Group: ' + groupName + ' not found.');
    else console.log(JSON.stringify(group));
    });

    ad.getUsersForGroup(groupName, function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (! users) console.log('Group: ' + groupName + ' not found.');
    else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify('Users: ',users));
    }
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log('Authentication failed!');
  }
});
```

Any ideas would be quite appreciated.

Comment: Is it finding the group when you use `ad.findGroup`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes, it does.

Comment: And just to confirm, the group does actually have members? Because you're outputting "group not found" when the list is empty, which could just mean there are no members.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I suspect that too but I haven’t been able to confirm this. ad.findUsersByGroup returns 0 also not only with this group but others. That’s weird cause is production, so ldapsearch could clear this up. On Monday I’ll know for sure. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @GabrielLuci What's even weirder is that ad.getUsersForGroup does not find a single user in the 217 groups available, which it cannot be. Is there the possibility of credentials used not having necessary privileges to search of users even though it can search for groups?

Comment: Scratch that: the groups are empty. I'll keep this post updated.

Comment: @GabrielLuci The groups are empty, but now I realize that this library does not give me the same amount of info that ldapsearch, or at least I don't how using the opts parameter. Could give me a hand here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a wrong domain component, so the library is alright, it all works now.